# C++ function call results in garbage parameters

Tags: c++, memory

ASI have a C++ function that looks like this:

```c++
static const unsigned int unknown = (unsigned)-1;

static inline char *
duplicateStringValue( const char *value, 
                      unsigned int length = unknown )
{
   if ( length == unknown )
      length = (unsigned int)strlen(value);
   char *newString = static_cast<char *>( malloc( length + 1 ) );
   ASSERT( newString != 0, "Failed to allocate string value buffer" );
   memcpy( newString, value, length );
   newString[length] = 0;
   return newString;
}
```

(This happens to be in the jsoncpp library, but I'm pretty sure that's orthogonal to the problem)

The issue is that according to GDB, the function is arriving on the stack with parameters `("", 31135568)`.  The program tries and fails to allocate 31 megabytes, hits the assert and dies.

By examining the frame above `dulpicateStringValue()` with GDB, I can see that it is being invoked with the first parameter pointing to a small string on the heap, and the second parameter left out.  In other words, as far as I can tell the function call is incorrectly getting garbage values for parameters.

I'm truly stumped by this.  The only idea I have is that `dulpicateStringValue()` is called many times before this successfully, but at this point the stack is ~25 frames deep, much deeper than usual (as far as I can tell).  Perhaps the stack and the heap are colliding and scribbling all over each other?

If anyone has some insights or has encountered something similar, I'd love to hear about it.

**Edit:** In response to questions, the function is being called as

```
value_.string_ = duplicateStringValue( other.value_.string_ );
```

where other.value_ is a union described by GDB as

```
value_ = {int_ = 34536679944, uint_ = 34536679944,
    real_ = 1.7063387081744787e-313, bool_ = 8,
    string_ = 0x80a8bea08 "boolean", map_ = 0x80a8bea08}
```

The code for the union:

```
union ValueHolder
{
    LargestInt int_;
    LargestUInt uint_;
    double real_;
    bool bool_;
    char *string_;
    ObjectValues *map_;
} value_;
```

**Edit 2:** @MarkRansom asked how the parameters are getting on the stack.  In fact, they're not, GDB is reading them straight out of the register:

```
(gdb) f 1
#1  0x000000080663377e in duplicateStringValue (value=0x80aac9a10 "", length=31135568) at json_value.cpp:60
60     ASSERT( newString != 0, "Failed to allocate string value buffer" );
(gdb) p &length
Address requested for identifier "length" which is in register $rsi
(gdb) p &value
Address requested for identifier "value" which is in register $r13
```

Comment: You say this is a C++ function, but it's returning a block allocated with `malloc()` rather than `new[]`. Is it possible somebody's calling `delete[]` on that pointer, and making a mess of things?

Comment: If this is C++ why mix malloc and new? And why not just using `std::string`.

Comment: Can we see the code that calls this function?

Comment: How is this function called? (very important)

Comment: Your function doesn't account for the case where `value` is NULL.

Comment: Oy, oy, oy. So given your edit, perhaps the call to duplicateStringValue() is being made, by accident, when the value_ union is holding some other type?

Comment: ThomasMatthews, jeffamaphone: see the edit.

Ernest, Jesus: this isn't our code, it's a third party open-source library that we call into about 20 frames up.  Also, the assert is hit before the function ever returns, so I don't think that mixing memory management schemes is the problem.

Thomas: This is true, but it's also not what's causing the problem.

Comment: Since the function is inline, how do the parameters get on the stack? Perhaps your debugger is misleading you.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill: I could see that, but what I pasted in the edit is what GDB reports for `other.value_` in the frame above `duplicateStringValue()`, so other.value_.string_ should be a valid pointer.  Also, that doesn't explain the way the second parameter is being mangled.

Comment: @MarkRansom: see Edit 2.

Comment: @Quonux: string_ is a char*, 0x80a8bea08 is the address, "boolean" is the value.

Comment: @dan, *but*  bool_ = 8,
    string_ = 0x80a8bea08 "boolean", map_ = 0x80a8bea08} are from a memory address where 0x08 0xea 0x8b 0x0a is repeated

Comment: @Quonux: Isn't that what we would expect from a union - all the fields have the same value, (0x80a8bea08), it just depends on whether you interpret it as a bool or a char*.

Comment: @Dan ofcourse, i didn't notice the union :/